# How to get rid of this routing error related to favicon.ico

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, favicon

Any ideas on how to get rid of this error.

Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 132.175.48.49 at 2012-12-18 11:20:59 +0000

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have such a line (most likely in your application.html.erb, or some other template):

```
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

If you do, just change it to:

```
<link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

Comment: Note this still got the "route" error, but had success with a less-popular answer on this other thread, ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687506/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-get-favicon-ico-in-rails ), which seems to have finally made this Rails bug go away: <link href="<%= image_path("favicon.ico") %>" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" /> - then repeat that with an 'img/png' type and png file, for the browsers that seem to prefer a png file.