# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico") in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have tried to use

```
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

as well as this

```
<link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

but I am still seeing this error in the log file

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):
```

the favicon.ico is there in public folder (I have also put it in app/assets folder too)

How to fix this error ?

Comment: Try to add the favicon.ico in the root directory of a web server and try again.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You're getting this error because you don't have a `favicon.ico` in your `public/` directory of your application. Because the file doesn't exist there, Rails moves on, looking for a route to match against `/favicon.ico` in the `config/routes.rb`.

You can fix this in one of two ways

1. Manually place the `favicon.ico` file in the `public/` directory of your application.
2. Put the `favicon.ico` in `app/assets/images/` and then change your `<link ...` tag to use [`image_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_path)

   ```
   <link href="<%= image_path("favicon.ico") %>" rel="shortcut icon" />
   ```

   This will place the `favicon.ico` in `public/assets/favicon.ico`, **not** in the document root.

I suggest sticking with **#1** above.

---

As for **why** this request is even showing up in your logs, many modern browsers look in the root of the domain for `/favicon.ico` to use for bookmarking, or presentation in a tab or the address bar. This is why it's a good idea to keep the `favicon.ico` in the root of your domain, in case a browser decides (for whatever reason) to ignore your `<link rel="icon shortcut" ...` tag.

Comment: I had to do both #1 and #2. I was using the favicon_link_tag helper.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right. I had my favicon configuration all setup correctly but I was still occasionally seeing these errors. It's hard to confirm but my guess is that some devices/browsers/UserAgents are hard-coded to look for it in the public directory as favicon.ico. We one in the public directory just to satisfy those requests and the errors went away.

Answer (score 7):

This is what Rails generates in application.html.erb by default:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico', :rel => 'shortcut icon' %>
```

It doesn't find favicon.ico this way when it's under /public

It works correctly (finds favicon.ico under /public) if you change the tag to:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting `favicon.ico` in my public folder wasn't working, so I combined some of the other answers to come up with this simple working method.

Copy the output of [`favicon_link_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/favicon_link_tag) and inject `image_path` like so:

```
<link href="<%= image_path("favicon.ico") %>" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
```

Now place `favicon.ico` in your `assets/images` folder and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

Put the **favicon.ico** in **app/assets/images/** and then add

```
<link href="<%= image_path("favicon.ico") %>" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

in the layout file.

This works for me.